# Need reference for SOAP API testing using Karate. Could not access working example link in Karate github Readme

Tags: karate

Need reference for SOAP API testing using Karate. Could not access working example link in Karate github Readme. Below is the link address

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/soap.feature

Can someone please post any references that you may have for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-demo

And then you will find the right link, just look for `soap`.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to my session: https://youtu.be/1iYhW_QVW0w

I have created sessions on GET, POST, PUT, DELETE services from rest service, refer them